# O que é e para que serve o ListIterator?

Tags: java, lista, groovy

Qual seria a função do `ListIterator`? Possuo uma variável do tipo `List`, que recebe as informações do meu Banco de Dados PostgreSQL, preciso acessar as informações dessa variável do tipo `List` porém ao utilizar o metodo `get()` para selecionar a informação de determinado Index eu estou tendo como retorno a referência desse registro e não as suas informações. Com o listIterator eu consigo acessar as informações da minha variável do tipo List?

```
def i = 0;
def x = 0;
def z = transportadorasBanco.size();
def y = listaTransportadoras.size();
logger.info("Registros BDM: "+ z)
logger.info("Registros Banco de Dados PostgreSQL: "+ y)

def itemBDM = []
def itemPost = []

while (x <= (z - 1)){
    while (i <= (y - 1)){
        if (transportadorasBanco.get(x).toString().equals(listaTransportadoras.get(i).toString())){
            logger.info("POSSICAO BDM: " +x)
            logger.info("POSSICAO POSTGRESQL: " +i)
            logger.info("IGUAIS")
            logger.info(transportadorasBanco.get(x).toString())
            logger.info(listaTransportadoras.get(i).toString())
            logger.info("")
        }
        else {
            logger.info("POSSICAO BDM: " +x)
            logger.info("POSSICAO POSTGRESQL: " +i)
            logger.info("DIFERENTES")
            logger.info(transportadorasBanco.get(x).toString())
            logger.info(listaTransportadoras.get(i).toString())
            logger.info("")
        }
        i++;
    }
    x++;
    i = 0;
}
```

Comment: Essa sua `List` é de números inteiros?

Comment: Tem o números inteiros e strings

Comment: Pode dar um exemplo em código do seu método `get` não retornando as informações que você quer?

Comment: Editei minha pergunta, com o script em groovy onde tento acessara as informações da variável

Comment: As listas `transportadorasBanco` e `listaTransportadoras` são listas de que?

Comment: Estou programando em um programa para desenvolver BPM para desenvolver processos, nessa ferramenta tem o BDM (Business Data Model), um banco de dados de negócio, então, a variável `transportadorasBanco` recebe os valores do BDM e a variável `listaTransportadoras` recebe as informações do PostgreSQL

Comment: Mas você saberia me dizer pelo menos a função do `ListIterator`?

Comment: Um `ListIterator` é um `Iterator` específico para listas. Além dos métodos que ele herda de um `Iterator`, ele possui métodos que permitem percorrer a lista em ambos os sentidos e modificar a lista durante a iteração.

Comment: E eu consigo através do `ListIterator` comparar informações da minha lista, por exemplo tirar os códigos repetidos?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53955/discussion-between-felipe-marinho-and-r-santos).