# O que seria Iteração?

Tags: terminologia, iterator

Em uma pergunta que fiz, eu questionei o que era e qual seria a função do `ListIterator`, então surgiu o termo **iteração**, o que seria isso?

[Link para pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/185456/o-que-%C3%A9-e-para-que-serve-o-listiterator)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> iteração | s. f. derivação fem. sing. de iterar
>
> i·te·ra·ção substantivo feminino
>
> Repetição.
>
> "iteração", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha],
> 2008-2013, https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/itera%C3%A7%C3%A3o [consultado
> em 20-02-2017].

Talvez a palavra "iterar" soe nova, mas provavelmente já ouviu "reiterar". Acho que todo mundo entende que "re-iterar" é repetir a iteração. Ou seja repetir aquilo que já deveria ser sabido, porque já foi feito uma ou mais vezes antes. Reiterar é iterar de novo depois da primeira iteração, é algo separado da iteração original. Uma iteração ocorre em conjunto.

Em computação toda repetição da execução de um bloco de comandos que ocorre infinitamente ou com o encerramento em determinado momento atendendo alguma condição é uma iteração.

Muito usado para percorrer todos, ou parte dos, elementos de uma sequência de dados.

Esta técnica se contrapões à [recursão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107657/101) que é um mecanismo diferente que consegue obter o mesmo resultado.

Então um `for`, `foreach`, `while`, `do...while`, `repeat...until`, `goto` que volta pra trás, `loop`, `each`, `dolist`, `PERFORM`, etc. todos eles são sintaxes do mecanismo que provoca iterações no código.

Então é só um jeito mais bonito de dizer que vai repetir.

Podemos dizer "faz um incremento em cada iteração" que é o mesmo que "faz um incremento em cada repetição" ou ainda "faz um incremento em cada vez que dá uma volta no laço"

Naquele contexto é justamente isto, estava falando para repetir em cada vez que executa todo o bloco de comandos ali contidos.

Por consequência o iterador é o mecanismo que faz ou colabora na repetição. Ou é gerido pela linguagem (quando compila/interpreta) ou é um objeto da biblioteca que gerencia as repetições indicando onde está e se deve parar.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Perfeita explicação, linguagem simples e de fácil entendimento