# foreach é um loop ou iterador? Ou pode ser os dois?

Tags: c#, loop, foreach

Em um vídeo tutorial o instrutor afirmou para não cair na besteira de achar que o foreach é um loop, e foi veemente que ele era um iterador.

Existem casos onde podemos percorrer os items de um array utilizando foreach como uma versão "compacta do for".

> Ou seja, quando usamos foreach para arrays ou matrizes, no fundo
>   estamos o usando como uma versão compacta do loop for. Quando o usamos
>   para iterar coleções, ele é de fato um VERDADEIRO iterador pois
>   "acessa" os métodos da IEnumerator

A afirmação está correta? Alguém pode acrescentar algo sobre isso?

Segue código exemplo:

```
//foreach com Arrays
    int[] array = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    foreach (int item in array) 
    {
      Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
```

No entanto, o compilador do C# gera código C# equivalente ao CIL gerado:

```
//Código C# equivalente ao CIL gerado
    int[] tempArray;
    int[] array = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    tempArray = array;
     for (int counter = 0; (counter < tempArray.Length); counter++) {
       int item = tempArray[counter];
       Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
```

O código acima foi retirado do livro:
**Essential C-6.0, 5th Edition [ Autor Mark Michaelis ] página 582**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Este trecho do livro "Listing  14.6 demonstrates a simple foreach **loop** iterating over an array ..." é esclarecedor.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Em geral videoaulas são feitas por pessoas que mal entendem a língua, quanto mais linguagens de programação. Não vou falar de caso específico, mas sempre tenha isso em mente. Até existem coisas boas, em geral em inglês e são pagas, como as da [Pluralsight](https://www.pluralsight.com/).

Tudo que é executado diretamente em repetição é um *loop*, ou laço em português. Então ambos são *loops* sim.

Se a intenção era dizer que o `foreach` não faz o processo tradicional que se costuma fazer em um `for`, também está errado.

O `foreach` é um mecanismo de iterar com uma coleção de dados. A maneira como isto será feito depende de alguns fatores. A forma mais comum é usar um iterador fornecido pela coleção, mas é possível usar o mesmo algoritmo do `for` em casos como o `array` e `string`. Embora não exista, nada impede de no futuro ter outros mecanismos ou outros objetos que iteram sem um iterador pronto.

Vejamos o código usando as duas formas:

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class C {
    public static void Main() {
        int[] array = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
        foreach (int item in array) WriteLine(item);
        var lista = new List<int>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
        foreach (int item in lista) WriteLine(item);
        var texto = "123456";
        foreach (char item in texto) WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/6R3JXI). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ovNRsa). E veja [descompilado no **SharpLab**](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#K4Zwlgdg5gBCAuBDeYDGMDKBPBBTAtgHQDCA9hCKQDa4DcAsAFCiSzZ5FlU2orkiEA4rgi4ATmgaMADsABGVNDFRVEIEDGIwA3kxj6YshUoTIlAN1JgAJjACyiSAAoAlDr0HPkeAG0AujCIYmKIWDAAvDCiAO4w3v7aAIwANDAATKkAzKkALKkArKkAbAC+Up6eAGakYriIqAAWME7ecfAEcRCBwaFuuowVgzAA6hLtADKQuC3t+C7lQyUeg+ZBMIqmEVG4sZMIADzeAHxJqRkw2TB5MIUwpQuD1bX1TS0Q8G0dkOtgpn3LQ30ozAEymMwI8wBniWAyGqzEMHaAA94KQtgAiRJpTI5fJFdEPCpPOqNZqNNYgr5dZGo/6wwFAsa4SaicFzQnQgEwkpAA=). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/ForEach.cs).

Claro que a forma de o descompilador regera o fonte depende da qualidade dele, mas fica claro que no caso do *array* transforma em algo sem iterador fornecido por ele, assim como *string*, e com uma lista um iterador pronto é usado, por isso ele consegue reconstruir o próprio `foreach`. Mas o `foreach` com iterador na verdade é equivalente a este código:

```
IEnumerator<int> enumerator = lista.GetEnumerator();
try {
    while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
        int item = enumerator.Current;
        WriteLine(item);
    }
} finally {
    IDisposable disposable = enumerator as IDisposable;
    if (disposable != null) disposable.Dispose();
}
```

Portanto é um *loop* também.

Note que mesmo o `for` usa um iterador, mas é um manual que o próprio programador controla como quiser.

Veja o que é [iteração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/185497/101).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta @bigown. Editei na própria pergunta a referência bibliográfica na qual o autor cita a questão da CIL sobre o uso do foreach para array. O instrutor citado, disse que o array implementa a IEnumerable de "fábrica" o que faz com que o foreach acesse diretamente os "super-poderes" da IEnumerator. 

Pode acrescentar algo sobre isso?

Comment: POsso dizer que ele não sabe muito bem o que tá falando, o compilador faz uma otimização que desconsidera o `IEnumerator` e não acessa nada diretamente, e vai do 0 ao seu tamanho, como você faria manualmente com um `for`, como já foi demonstrado.

Comment: @EduardoMoscatelli, [aqui](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/148691/Internals-of-loops-While-For-and-ForEach) você pode ter uma noção de como o compilador trabalha com loops, no caso o que ele vai gerar para (for, foreach e while)

Answer (score 7):

Tal como foi dito na resposta do @Maniero, o `foreach` é um loop porque ele executa um bloco de código repetidamente, de forma não recursiva, tal como o `while`, `for` ou `do-while`, ou até mesmo `goto` em alguns cenários.

Eu não sei o que o tutor quis explicar, mas se eu fosse o tutor explicaria que o `foreach` é uma forma simplificada de usar um [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx).

Como pode ver o `IEnumerable<T>` tem apenas um método o `IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()`. Se o `foreach` nao existisse teria que escrever um código parecido a este para percorrer os elementos:

```
IEnumerable<string> values = new[]{"olá"};
var it = values.GetEnumerator();
while(it.MoveNext()){
    Console.WriteLine(it.Current);
}
```

O `foreach` permite-lhe então ter um código mais simples. Na verdade sempre que usa o `foreach` ele na realidade gera um código parecido ao que mostrei.

Porém a história não acaba aqui. Se prestar atenção você vê que o [`IEnumerator<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb(v=vs.110).aspx) implementa também a interface `IDisposable`. E na realidade quando você usa o `foreach` a plataforma também gera código para chamar o `Dispose`.

Ou seja falta uma coisa no código que mostrei anteriormente:

```
IEnumerable<string> values = new[]{"olá"};
var it = values.GetEnumerator();
using(it){
    while(it.MoveNext()){
        Console.WriteLine(it.Current);
    }
}
```

Agora sim, tem uma ideia geral de como o `foreach` funciona. O código gerado pelo `.NET` não deverá ser muito diferente desse.

**Nota** - A plataforma .NET está em evolução e é normal que eles tenham encontrado forma de gerar um código mais eficiente consoante a estrutura de dados que está a ser usada. Parece que segundo o livro citado pelo perguntador, eles encontraram uma forma de optimizar o código gerado para percorrer qualquer *array*, ou até mesmo qualquer `IList`

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta @BrunoCosta, gostei muito das tuas observações. Só me vem uma dúvida quando fala que o **foreach** é um loop e também uma forma simplificada de usar um IEnumerable<T>. Loops ao meu entender fazem repetições "irracionais", e me parece que quando o foreach tem acesso ao MoveNext da IEnumerator, ele passa a atuar como iterador não?

Tem algo a acrescentar sobre?

Comment: @Eduardo Moscatelli Um iterador é qualquer mecanismo que percorre uma sequencia dados. Como voce sugeriu, essa é a caracteristica adicional dum iterador em relacao a um loop. Nem todos os loops sao iteradores. Mas todos os iteradores precisam de loops ou recursividade.

Comment: Assino embaixo.

Answer (score 4):

Olá, achei está discussão um tanto quanto interessante, e apenas para complementar o que @BrunoCosta e @Maniero disseram, note que o seguinte código abaixo também funciona normalmente:

```
IEnumerable<string> itens = new string[1] { "meu texto" };

for (IEnumerator<string> it = itens.GetEnumerator(); it.MoveNext();)
{
    Console.WriteLine(it.Current);
}
```

Note que aqui também abri mão da *sintax sugar* proposta pelo `foreach` utilizando o `for`, sendo possível eu iterar com uma coleção `IEnumerable<string>`.

**Nota:** O código acima gerado tem apenas intuito disciplinar, com fins de mostrar que tanto for como `foreach` apresentam características de uma estrutura de *loop*, bem como para iterar coleções. Não recomendo o uso desta abordagem, justamente por termos o próprio `foreach` para fazê-lo.

Comment: Muito obrigado pessoal, por todas as respostas. O instrutor em resposta ao meu questionamento disse que todos arrays implementam a interface IEnumerable e que não concordava comigo do foreach poder ser um loop também. Ainda tenho a dúvida se o uso do foreach para iterar um array simples ocorre com um fake do "for" criado pela CIL ou se ele de fato acessa todos os "poderes" da IEnumerator através da IEnumerable que já vem de fábrica em todos os arrays. 

Alguém pra acender uma lanterna nesse túnel escuro? hahah

Comment: @EduardoMoscatelli como eu disse, ele tem problemas até de interpretação de texto. Ele sequer sabe o que é um *loop*. Só entenda que no CIL não tem nada de `for`, ele tem mecanismo mais baixo nível que um `for` que já é uma abstração. Mas não há uso do `IEnumerable` em um *loop*  de *array*, ainda que isto seja um detalhe de implementação e em tese nenhum programador precisa saber disto para programar corretamente, apenas é útil para entender um pouco mais do que programadores mais ingênuos.

Comment: Os problemas do código desta resposta é que ele faz a memória vazar e que um *array* não é compilado para algo equivalente a isto.

Comment: @bigown eu sei que um array não é compilado para isso, inclusive sei do vazamento de memória, mas como o próprio texto da resposta diz, é apenas um exemplo de como for e foreach trabalham iterando coleções, reforçando sua tese sobre loop, por motivos óbvios é claro que não recomendo o uso deste código, sendo apenas uma abordagem teórica sobre o assunto.

Comment: A questão do  *loop* é ok, é que achei que pode passar a impressão que é este código que é gerado, feito mais claramente o alerta, fica melhor.

Comment: @bigown ajustado resposta para melhores entendimentos futuros.