# O que é e pra que serve IEnumerable e IEnumerator?

Tags: c#, .net, interface, enumerable

Fiz um combo de perguntas sobre `IEnumerable` e `IEnumerator` pra não só ajudar a mim como a todos que necessitam de uma explicação mais didática.

**Pergunta 1**

> Alguém poderia explicar de forma mais didática pra que serve estas
>   interfaces e quais as vantagens que elas trazem para iterações que um
>   "loop simples" não traz?

**Pergunta 2**

> Tendo em vista que a IEnumerable só tem um método que chama a
>   IEnumerator e que para iterar uma coleção não temos a obrigatoriedade
>   de implementar a IEnumerable, segue uma dúvida:
>   **Qual a relação da IEnumerable com a IEnumerator?**

**Pergunta 3**

> Alguém pode me explicar o porque esse código funciona mesmo não sendo
>   os códigos mais comumente ensinados para implementação da IEnumerator?

```
//IEnumerator
      int[] array = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; 
      IEnumerator o = array.GetEnumerator();
      while (o.MoveNext())
      {
        Console.WriteLine(o.Current);    
      }
```

---

**Sobre a relação do foreach com a IEnumerator/IEnumerable**

Vocês podem obter bastante informação [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/188067/foreach-%C3%A9-um-loop-ou-iterador-ou-pode-ser-os-dois).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Alguém poderia explicar de forma mais didática pra que serve estas interfaces

`IEnumerable` é uma interface que marca as classes que desejam implementá-la para que se saiba que ela possa ter iterável através de um iterador. Obviamente que isso só deve ser usado em objetos que seja sequências de dados, caso contrário não faz sentido iterar ali. O método é usado para obter o iterador. Na maioria das vezes a implementação deste método é igual ou muito parecida.

Sempre que implementar a `IEnumerable` terá que implementar, de alguma forma, na classe ou em outro local a interface `IEnumerator`.

O iterador é definido pela interface `IEnumerator` que propõe ter o mecanismo necessária para iterar, ou seja, precisa de um estado com o objeto atual ([`Current`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator.current?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-7.0#System_Collections_IEnumerator_Current)), qual é o próximo item da lista ([`MoveNext()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator.movenext?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-7.0#System_Collections_IEnumerator_MoveNext)) e como reiniciar a varredura do iterador ([`Reset()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator.reset?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-7.0#System_Collections_IEnumerator_Reset)).

> quais as vantagens que elas trazem para iterações que um "loop simples" não traz?

Se a linguagem não determinar como fazer um laço em uma sequência de dados, a única forma de você criar um tipo que seja uma sequência de dados iterável é fornecendo um mecanismo que diga:

- como deve pegar o dado
- o próximo e
- como recomeçar.

Seu tipo deve fornecer o código que faça isso de forma apropriada e se possível com a melhor performance possível para o seu caso. No caso a linguagem faz em *array* e *string*, então em tese esses tipos não precisariam ter essas interfaces, mas eles têm para uso em outras situações que a linguagem não controla.

> Tendo em vista que a IEnumerable só tem um método que chama a IEnumerator e que para iterar uma coleção não temos a obrigatoriedade de implementar a IEnumerable, segue uma dúvida: Qual a relação da IEnumerable com a IEnumerator?

Isso não é bem verdade. Até é possível na maioria dos casos não implementar a `IEnumerable` em uma coleção, mas um monte de coisa não será possível ser feita. Nem podemos considerá-la uma coleção, pelo menos não uma iterável. Será uma bela de uma gambiarra. Tem coleção que simplesmente não é possível iterar sem fazer algo totalmente fora do padrão. E o intuito dessas interfaces é manter uma forma padrão de fazer as coisas.

> Alguém pode me explicar o porque esse código funciona mesmo não sendo os códigos mais comumente ensinados para implementação da IEnumerator?

O código funciona porque é o que ele tem que fazer.

- ele pega o iterador e joga em um objeto
- o `MoveNext()` pega o próximo elemento da sequência, no caso deve pegar o primeiro
- acessa o elemento dentro do laço
- volta verificar se tem o próximo item para decidir se vai continuar ou não, já que o `MoveNext()` retorna um booleano.

Exatamente como isso funciona internamente é problema do iterador específico, é detalhe de implementação.

Na verdade esse código não é bom porque ele vaza memória deixando o iterador vivo mesmo após terminar seu uso. Em outras situações é possível que um *cast* seja necessário para usar o elemento já que ele retorna um `object`, a não ser que use um `IEnumerator<T>` que permite retornar o tipo real do objeto. Tudo isso o compilador põe pra você, por isso é melhor usar o `foreach` do que fazer na mão, o compilador sabe o que está fazendo, o programador nem sempre.

O `foreach` só pode trabalhar em objetos que possuam a interface `IEnumerable` já que ele precisa iterar na sequência de dados.

No *link* fornecido na pergunta realmente tem como o código fica depois de compilado (é feito um *lowering*).

Se o .NET fosse escrito hoje seria diferente, talvez a [ideia do Jared Parsons](http://blog.paranoidcoding.com/2014/08/19/rethinking-enumerable.html) fosse a implementação, que é muito melhor que a adotada.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 5):

Na **Pergunta 3** acredito que em virtude dos **arrays já implementarem a IEnumerable de "fábrica"** conseguimos "instanciar" o enumerador através do método `array.GetEnumerator()` e sua consequente atribuição ao objeto `IEnumerator o`.

> Devemos levar em consideração, que o uso da IEnumerator neste caso é
>   apenas como finalidade de estudo pois fica muito claro que a melhor
>   prática de iteração para o exemplo é utilizar um "loop simples" (
>   for/while ou até mesmo o foreach).