# O que é um iterador?

Tags: terminologia, iterator

Em PHP , quando preciso que determinada classe tenha determinado comportamento na chamada de `foreach`, eu implemento uma interface chamada `Generator`.

Em Python parece existir também `__iter__`, que muda o comportamento do objeto em relação ao `for`.

Já ouvi também em várias outras linguagens ([Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html), [Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iteratores_e_geradores) e afins) o uso do termo *Iterator*, em operações similares. E vejo que geralmente trata-se de uma implementação OOP.

- Afinal de contas, o que é um Iterator ou Iterador?
- O uso do termo *iterador* ou *iterator* está relaciona diretamente à orientação a objetos?
- Um iterador sempre terá relação com `for`, `foreach`,`while` e afins?

Comment: Se não for, editar pra deixar mais claro o que essas não respondem.

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/191582/101

Comment: Talvez dup também: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/185497/101

Comment: @bigown, vixe, deixar como referência :p