# Por que a IDE transformou meu for-loop em um for-each?

Tags: java, array, for, característica-linguagem, ide

Fiz um simples código para treinar o uso de *arrays*:

```
public class Segundo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] nomes = new String[3];
        nomes[0] = "joao";
        nomes[1] = "Gabriel";
        nomes[2] = "Lucas";
        for (int index = 0; index < nomes.length; index++) {
            System.out.println(nomes[index]);
        }

    }
}
```

Ao dar uma inspecionada no código com o botão direito, cliquei em uma sugestão e organizou desta maneira:

```
public class Segundo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] nomes = new String[3];
        nomes[0] = "joao";
        nomes[1] = "Gabriel";
        nomes[2] = "Lucas";
        for (String nome : nomes) {
            System.out.println(nome);
        }

    }
}
```

Qual o motivo do `for` ter sido resumido dessa forma?

Comment: As 2 formas são equivalentes. A segunda é chamada de [*enhanced for*](https://blogs.oracle.com/corejavatechtips/using-enhanced-for-loops-with-your-classes) e é mais sucinta (e preferível se vc só quer iterar pelos valores, sem se importar com o índice, por exemplo - mas não se resume a isso, claro). Agora **porque** o seu editor sugeriu isso, é outra história: cada IDE tenta ser mais "inteligente" que as outras e dar sugestões de "melhorias", e isso varia muito de um para outro. Não quer dizer que vc deva seguir sempre, claro...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso é um trabalho do IDE (especificamente o que está usando). É absolutamente desnecessário, mas útil, principalmente para o aprendizado. veja mais em [O que é linguagem de programação, IDE e compilador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101).

O IDE escolheu uma forma melhor para escrever o mesmo código. Como ele identificou facilmente um padrão que dava para fazer indica também que o seu código não tinha maiores problemas. Se ele não encontrasse algo facilmente reconhecível e que desse para mudar sem alterar qualquer mínimo comportamento do código, ele não faria (assim espero, se fizesse, teria que jogar fora algo tão ruim).

A função do IDE é justamente fazer algo mais por você e o algoritmo dele é mais sofisticado que do compilador. O compilador deve apenas validar o código, otimizá-lo e gerar um código final, portanto ele não deve fazer nada além disso, seria complicado ter que lidar com tudo, ficaria ineficiente e atrapalharia a função principal.

O código que ele gerou acaba sendo na prática igual ao que foi escrito originalmente. Mas a forma dele é mais curta, legível e menos propenso a erros. Nas próximas vezes pode fazer assim que o resultado é o mesmo.

Essa forma gerada funciona bem para qualquer coleção de dados. Para outras coleções que não sejam *array* a forma originalmente escrita não funciona, precisaria de um código diferente, isso é chamado [padrão Iterador](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern) ([veja como é feito em C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/188067/101), é quase igual ao Java). Ele é tão útil que a linguagem abstraiu-o.

Então o código gerado é uma forma de abstrair a forma de avaliar todos elementos de uma coleção, e o compilador saberá o que fazer por baixo dos panos em cada tipo de coleção, seja um *array*, uma *string* ou outra coleção da biblioteca, ou até mesmo uma criada por você, se você criar de forma adequada que o compilador consiga compreender, seguindo o *pattern* definido. Existe uma técnica para criar suas próprias coleções adequadamente, não vem ao caso aqui.

O segundo `for` é mais alto nível, o código diz que deve pegar item por item de `nomes` e jogar em cada passo do laço o valor na variável `nome`. O primeiro está mandando andar pelos elementos manualmente, fazendo uma aritmética de índice e se não fizer certo dá erro. Olha quantos mecanismos você tem que manipular manualmente que pode cometer algum erro. Note que a variável não precisa de índice no `for` melhorado.

Esse `for` mais abstrato em outras linguagens é chamado de `for each`, então é *para cada elemento* (na pergunta original não tinha isso, o AP não sabia, então a edição não foi boa)).

O `for` mais bruto ainda é útil em alguns raros casos que precisa "navegar" pela coleção de forma fora do padrão. Prefira a forma mais moderna sempre que possível.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score -1):

Isto são auto-sugestões, é quando a IDE lhe apresenta uma ou mais alternativas melhores para o caso, seja para encurtar o código, melhorar a legibilidade, evitar futuros erros ou realmente direcionar o caminho do seu código para o melhor possível.

Sempre que houverem essas sugestões procure aprender com elas e sempre as utilize.

Atualmente também é comum a IDE transformar algumas funções em lambda-expressions, o que torna o código mais legível (exemplo o método run), com o tempo você vai estar programando melhor pois a IDE lhe ajuda nisso.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).