# Encontrar quantidade de vezes que um caractere aparece numa palavra usando recursividade

Tags: c, funções, recursão

> Desenvolva um algoritmo que leia uma palavra (*string*) e um caractere e retorne o número de vezes que esse caractere aparece na palavra. O algoritmo deve ser recursivo.
>
> Exemplos de Entrada e Saída:
>
> Entrada:
>
> ```
> araraquara a
> ```
>
> Saída:
>
> ```
> 5
> ```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 30

int ocorrencias(char palavra[], char letra){

    if(letra == '\0'){
        return 0;
    }

    int i;
    //palavra[i+1];

    if(letra == palavra[i]){
        return 1 + ocorrencias(palavra[i++], letra);
    }else{
        return ocorrencias(palavra[i++], letra);
    }
}

int main(){

    char palavra[MAX];
    char letra;

    scanf("%s %c", palavra, &letra);

    int ocorre = ocorrencias(palavra, letra);
    
    printf("%d", ocorre);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 5):

O código tem alguns problemas, mas o principal deles é que ele [não é o ideal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107657/101) para [recursão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21551/101). Toda vez que tem que passar um estado de controle da recursão, a [iteração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/185497/101) costuma ser melhor. Este é um exercício para aprender fazer o mecanismo certo para a situação errada. É este tipo de coisa que gera vícios de programação.

No código mesmo precisa comparar se o caractere do texto em análise é um [*null terminator*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177619/101). Comparar com o caracteres de busca não faz sentido.

Depois qual o índice que deve ser usado para pegar a letra do texto a ser analisado? Não tem isso. Houve uma tentativa de criar essa variável, mas ela localmente não serve para nada. Tem que ficar passando ela em cada chamada. Tem que criar um parâmetro novo. E isto torna o algoritmo de iteração mais eficiente e mais intuitivo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 30

int ocorrencias(char palavra[], char letra, int i) {
    if (palavra[i] == '\0') return 0;
    return (letra == palavra[i]) + ocorrencias(palavra, letra, i + 1);
}

int main() {
    char palavra[MAX];
    char letra;
    scanf("%s %c", palavra, &letra);
    printf("%d", ocorrencias(palavra, letra, 0));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/lD1kdO). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/tpejsxet-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Function/CountRecursion.c).

Para evitar isto tem que usar um truque para ir andando no caractere seguinte em cada recursão, veja na resposta do Victor Stafusa. O que fica mais confuso ainda. Mais fácil fazer assim:

```
int ocorrencias(char palavra[], char letra) {
    int contagem = 0;
    int = 0;
    while (palavra[i] != '\0') contagem += letra == palavra[i++];
    return contagem;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/Occours.c).

Dá para fazer em uma ou duas linhas, mas não acho que compense. Ninguém se perde nisto e é mais rápido.

Comment: Olha que coincidência, postamos respostas com poucos segundos de diferença e o código da função `ocorrencias` ficou quase idêntico. A diferença é que você fez a solução passando o índice como um parâmetro extra e eu fiz a solução incrementando o ponteiro.

Comment: Eu ia por os *links* e lendo a sua resolvi fazer referência a ela que resolve o problema do parâmetro.

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro, comecemos com isso:

```
if(letra == palavra[i]){
    return 1 + ocorrencias(palavra[i++], letra);
}else{
    return ocorrencias(palavra[i++], letra);
}
```

Dá para eliminar essa repetição da chamada recursiva que tem no `if` e no `else` assim:

```
int a = (letra == palavra[i]);
int b = ocorrencias(palavra[i++], letra);
return a + b;
```

E isso por sua vez pode ser simplificado nisso:

```
return (letra == palavra[i]) + ocorrencias(palavra[i++], letra);
```

Mas esse ainda não é o seu problema. Para entender o seu problema, vamos ver qual que é o valor de `i`:

```
int i;
```

Ou seja, **a variável `i` está sem valor!** Esse é o principal motivo pelo qual não funciona. Logo, `palavra[i]` e `palavra[i++]` não são expressões que terão sentido.

Para arrumar isso, o que você está tentando fazer é olhar a primeira letra da palavra com o `letra == palavra[i]` e passar recursivamente o restante da palavra com `palavra[i++]`. Ora, a primeira letra da palavra é a que está no índice zero, e portanto você usa `palavra[0]` ao invés de `palavra[i]`. Para o restante da palavra, você pega o endereço do segundo caractere, ou seja, `&(palavra[1])`. Assim sendo, esse código fica assim:

```
return (letra == palavra[0]) + ocorrencias(&(palavra[1]), letra);
```

E note também que agora, a variável `i` não é mais utilizada e pode ser eliminada.

Entretanto, isso ainda não funciona porque a parte que olha o final da string ainda está errada:

```
if(letra == '\0'){
    return 0;
}
```

Isso verifica se a letra dada como entrada é uma string vazia. Ora, isso não verifica de forma nenhuma se a palavra já terminou. Assim sendo, o que você queria era isso:

```
if (palavra[0] == '\0') return 0;
```

E a sua função `ocorrencias` fica assim:

```
int ocorrencias(char palavra[], char letra) {
    if (palavra[0] == '\0') return 0;
    return (letra == palavra[0]) + ocorrencias(&(palavra[1]), letra);
}
```

Eis como fica o seu código completo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 30

int ocorrencias(char palavra[], char letra) {
    if (palavra[0] == '\0') return 0;
    return (letra == palavra[0]) + ocorrencias(&(palavra[1]), letra);
}

int main() {
    char palavra[MAX];
    char letra;

    scanf("%s %c", palavra, &letra);

    int ocorre = ocorrencias(palavra, letra);
    printf("%d", ocorre);

    return 0;
}
```

[Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.](http://ideone.com/2qR1hI)

Ah, ainda daria para reduzir a função `ocorrencias` um pouco mais deixando-a em uma só linha, mas aí você pode achar que isso já é exagero:

```
int ocorrencias(char palavra[], char letra) {
    return palavra[0] == '\0' ? 0 : (letra == palavra[0]) + ocorrencias(&(palavra[1]), letra);
}
```