# Acessar método toString a partir da classe genérica

Tags: java, herança, polimorfismo

Tenho uma classe genérica **Funcionário** e outras 3 classes especificas que herdam de funcionário. Dentro da classe Funcionário, tenho o método **toString**.

```
abstract class Funcionario {
    private String nome;
    private String documento;

    public String toString(){
         return "\nNome e Documento";
    }
}

class Motorista extends Funcionario {
    private String cnh;

    public String toString(){
        return "CNH";
    }
}

class Secretaria extends Funcionario {
    private String telefone;

    public String toString(){
        return "Telefone";
    } 
}

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Secretaria fulana = new Secretaria();
        System.out.println(fulana);

        Secretaria ciclana = new Secretaria();
        System.out.println(ciclana);

        Motorista beltrano = new Motorista();
        System.out.println(beltrano);
    }
}
```

Existem outras classes que também herdam de **Funcionario**. Existe algum modo, (talvez por polimorfismo) que eu possa 'iterar' sobre todos os objetos e executar o método toString de cada um?

Ao invés de chamar um objeto por vez dentro do `System.out.print`, há alguma maneira de economizar código?

Link para Código no Ideone [aqui](https://ideone.com/hTWfiQ).

Comment: Os código estão jogados demais, se a gente fosse tentar executar isso daria um monte de erro além do erro que você está perguntando, poderia fazer um [mcve] pra nos ajudar a ajudar você? Eu até acho que entendo o que quer, mas na forma atual eu posso acabar especulando uma coisa e ser outra.

Comment: O exemplo melhorou muito e vi que estava preparando no ideone o que facilitaria colocar o link pra gente *forkar*, mas agora ficou esquisito porque cada um desses objetos não tem relação entre eles para fazer aquele `for` inicial, sem ter algo que vincule todas classes de alguma forma em algum objeto, se for tudo espalhado em variáveis soltas, mesmo que na mesma função, o problema maior é este e não o polimorfismo. E não sei se os `toString()` ficaram significativos o suficiente para o que quer, mas pode ser que sim para o exemplo, só estou especulando nessa parte.

Comment: basta dentro dessas mesmas classes que herdam o metodo toString() fazer: @Override
public String toString(){
... espero que isso ajude

Comment: Se você tiver um array ou `ArrayList` de `Funcionario` é so iterar e chamar o `toString`. Não é dessa forma que tem ? Você tem 150 variaveis soltas de funcionarios como o exemplo dá a ideia ?

Comment: @Maniero Esqueci de relacionar os elementos através da herança. Mas basicamente a ideia é o reuso de código. Talvez eu esteja me expressando de forma errada, mas basicamente eu gostaria de saber a forma mais fácil de executar o método 'toString' em todos os objetos a partir da classe genérica.

Comment: O problema é que seu código é todo sobre outro problema que nada tem a ver com o que você está falando, e a gente está falando isso e você está ignorando. Existe um problema conceitual no seu uso do `toString()`, mas isso é outro assunto, o fato é que não tem dúvida alguma postada, você um código, ele funciona e tudo ok. Aí você fala de iterar, mas iterar o que? Objetos soltos? Isso não é possível, nem faz sentido. Primeiro precisa entender o que é uma iteração. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/185497/101. Se não está conseguindo se expressar corretamente precisa resolver isto p/ podermos ajudar

Comment: @Maniero O código é proveniente do projeto real, apenas achei melhor não inserir todos os campos e métodos pois não se fazem necessários para o caso. Entendo a ideia de iteração, por isso coloquei as aspas. A minha ideia é praticamente o que o user129943 citou, mas não queria fazer o uso de listas.

Comment: Infelizmente sem dizer o que quer fica complicado responder. Eu praticamente respondi nos comentários, mas e isto não é suficiente não sei do que se trata a pergunta.

Comment: @Maniero Haha! Vou tentar ser o mais objetivo possível.. Através da superclasse, eu consigo através do polimorfismo chamar o método toString de cada objeto que herdou de Funcionario?
Ao invés de chamar o Print de cada objeto individualmente.

Comment: Continua não dizendo nada útil e o fato de você aceitar uma resposta que você mesmo diz que não serve para você mostra que eu errei em não ter fechado a pergunta desde o início (a aceitação acabou sendo um desserviço para a comunidade). O que você quer não faz sentido e eu disse isso desde o princípio.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Então não entendi direito a pergunta.
Iterações são feitas sobre listas, se é isso que você quer você deveria armazenar todos os seus funcionários numa List, mas não há a necessidade de iterar sobre todos os objetos se a única informação que você precisa é quantas instancias foram criadas, basta buscar essa informação com o método size.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

abstract class Funcionario {
    protected String nome;
    protected String documento;

    public String toString(){
        return "\n--Funcionário--" +
               "\nNome: " + this.nome +
               "\nDocumento: " + this.documento;
    }
}

class Motorista extends Funcionario{

    Motorista(String nome, String documento) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.documento = documento;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "\n--Motorista--" +
               "\nNome: " + this.nome +
               "\nDocumento: " + this.documento;
    }
}

class Secretaria extends Funcionario{
    private String telefone;

    Secretaria(String nome, String documento, String telefone) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.documento = documento;
        this.telefone = telefone;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "\n--Secretaria--" +
               "\nNome: " + this.nome +
               "\nDocumento: " + this.documento +
               "\nTelefone: " + this.telefone;
    } 
}

public class Ideone {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        ArrayList<Funcionario> lista = new ArrayList();

        lista.add(new Secretaria("Fulana", "123.456.789-00", "3322-1234"));
        lista.add(new Secretaria("Ciclana", "578.367.263-30", "5854-8952"));
        lista.add(new Motorista("Beltrano", "654.786.324-54"));

        System.out.println("No momento existem " +lista.size()+ " funcionários cadastrados");

        for (Funcionario f : lista) {
            System.out.println(f);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: É praticamente isso que estou procurando, mas sem o uso de lista, estou interessado em saber como eu poderia fazer uso do polimorfismo para acessar esses métodos através da classe Funcionario.

Comment: É exatamente isso que estou fazendo no código. Estou guardando Secretaria e Motorista em uma lista de Funcionário (isso é possível porque Funcionário é a classe pai), e quando eu passo esse objeto para o println, que automaticamente invoca o toString, o toString implementado na classe filha é invocado. Faça o teste. 
Funcionario fulana = new Secretaria();
System.out.println(fulana);

Comment: Eu não queria implementar uma lista, mas após implementar o código que você forneceu funcionou perfeitamente. O pessoal do StackOverflow internacional me indicou o uso do 'super' ao invocar o método toString, e após implementar com a sua dica o algorítimo funcionou perfeitamente.