# O que há por trás do "for"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, característica-linguagem, for

Dia desses me deparei com uma dúvida de um usuário que queria imprimir uma *string*, mas com intervalo de tempo entre cada caractere, então sugeri que ele utilizasse o seguinte código:

```
from time import sleep
frase = ("Boa noite a todos!")
for i in range(len(frase)):
    print(frase[i],end = "")
    sleep(0.5)
```

Um outro usuário no mesmo fórum sugeriu a seguinte solução abaixo:

```
from time import sleep
frase = 'Boa noite'
for letra in frase: 
    print(letra, end="")
    sleep(0.5)
```

Fiquei curioso especialmente com essa linha de código: `for letra in frase:`

**Como o Python sabe que aquele caractere se chama letra?** O pior de tudo foi quando substituí o `letra` por `for bola in frase:` e o código continuou funcionando, aí sim *buguei* de vez.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Como o Python sabe que aquele caractere se chama letra?

A linha está dizendo.

> quando substituí o letra por for bola in frase: e o código continuou funcionando

E porque seria diferente?

Você tem liberdade de dar o nome que quiser para qualquer variável. Aconselha-se usar um nome significativo, mas pode escrever qualquer nome válido para um identificador em código seguindo as regras de sintaxe definidas para Python.

Na verdade seu código original já mostra isso, você usou `i` e também funcionou, ainda que seu código fazia um monte de coisa desnecessária. Você tentou reproduzir o `for` bruto de outras linguagens, que raramente é necessário. O `for`, também conhecido como *for each*, costuma ser mais adequado na maioria das situações porque ele é usado para "varrer" uma coleção de dados, é raro você precisar usar ele como um contador, como foi usado na sua resposta no fórum citado. O `for` tem como objetivo pegar uma coleção e ir jogando um elemento dele em uma variável para ser usada em cada passo, muito mais simples e menos chance de fazer algo errado.

Para sanar a questão colocada abaixo, se por acaso a interpretação for outra do que era a pergunta, e nada na pergunta indica ser outra coisa, e se for assim a pergunta não está clara, vou colocar mais sobre.

O `for`, pelo menos em Python, é um padrão de projeto, como muitos outros, que existem na sintaxe da linguagem para facilitar o uso de algo muito comum evitando erros, conforme já disse antes, e assim como é uma [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) e outros mecanismos.

Esse *design pattern* existe porque é comum precisarmos percorrer uma coleção de dados. Em Python a coleção mais conhecida é a lista, outra é o dicionário. Mas a mais usada é a coleção *string*, que nada mais é que uma lista de caracteres. Como ela é tão usada tem um literal que deixa você criar um valor com cada caractere sendo escrito junto sem separadores, apenas delimitado por aspas (simples ou duplas).

Toda coleção de dados possuem alguns mecanismos para manipularmos seu conteúdo. Um deles é o método `__iter__()`. Ele fornece um objeto que controla o acesso à lista de dados, e com este objeto você pode fazer algumas coisas, entre elas o mais importante é ir para o próximo item, com o `__next__()`.

Portanto se você for criar um tipo que seja uma coleção é sua obrigação criar estes métodos neste tipo para que processe adequadamente a [iteração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/185497/101).

O seu código na verdade é parecido com escrever:

```
tmp_iter = frase.__iter__()
while True:
    try:
        letra = tmp_iter.__next__()
        print(letra, end = "")
        sleep(0.5)
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Syntax/Iteration.py).

O que diga-se de passagem não é uma forma muito eficiente, mas Python não tem esse compromisso.

Obviamente que tem simplificação aí e tem várias outras formas de lidar com isso e métodos diferentes no processo.

Comment: Então basicamente ele interpretou a string como uma lista?

Comment: Uma *string*  é uma lista de caracteres. A tradução da palavra é cadeia, o que pode ser interpretada também como conjunto, coleção, sequência, algo que vai sendo colocado um atrás de outro.

Comment: Eu acho que a dúvida dele estava mais relacionada a achar que letra era um membro ou função especial do objeto frase.

Comment: @C.Felipe minha interpretação não é essa, e como a aceitação foi dada nesta resposta me parece que ele concordou com minha interpretação. Uma pena eu receber um negativo por uma resposta certa. Se eu usar o cri´terio da interpretação do que é a pergunta, eu poderia negativar a sua por você ter interpretado diferente do que eu interpretarei, mas obviamente não farei isto porque seria votar por motivos errados, como você fez.

Comment: Justo. Acho que quem tem que resolver isso é quem perguntou também, mudei meu voto.

Answer (score 6):

Veja a documentação sobre a [declaração for](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) e [iterators](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#iterators). Na declaração `for letra in frase:` temos o seguinte:

1. `for` chama a função `__iter__()` do objeto `frase`.
2. A função `__iter__()` retorna um objeto chamado **iterator**, que é capaz de acessar os sucessivos objetos de `frase` atravéz da função `__next__()`
3. O resultado da chamada de `__next__()` passa a ser guardado em `letra`.

Daí vem a magia que você observou. A declaração `for` não sabe, a princípio, como acessar os valores do objeto `frase`. Então o que ela faz é para pedir para `frase` um objeto que saiba. Esse objeto, chamado **iterator**, tem uma função chamada `__next__()` que é acessada pelo loop `for` e retorna próximo elemento da sequência. `letras` é só uma variável que recebe o resultado de `__next()`, ela poderia ter qualquer nome e não está relacionada de forma alguma ao objeto `frase`.

Para ficar menos abstrato, você pode implementar a declaração `for letra in frase:` no braço:

```
>>>frase = "Boa noite a todos!"
>>>iterador = frase.__iter__()
>>>iterator
<str_iterator object at 0x000001ADA25DCE80>
>>>letra = iterador.__next__()
>>>letra
'B'
>>>letra = iterador.__next__()
>>>letra
'o'
>>>letra = iterador.__next__()
>>>letra
'a'
```

Veja novamente que você poderia ter chamado `letra` de qualquer coisa. É só o objeto que guarda o resultado de `iterador.__next__()`.

Answer (score 4):

Acredito que você "bugou" para interpretar este novo código sugerido por um outro usuário do fórum já que a variável "frase" é apenas uma `string`, mas uma `string` é uma cadeia de caracteres (`char`), então quando você utilizar o `for` (que no Python também serve como `foreach`) ele pega a cadeia (`array`) de caracteres e então a percorre cada caractere ou seja e como se fosse um `array` desta forma:

```
['B', 'o', 'a', ' ', 'n', 'o', 'i', 't', 'e']
```

Agora veja o mesmo código com esta visão, como ele se torna mais simples e compreensível:

```
from time import sleep
frase = 'Boa noite'
for letra in frase: 
    print(letra, end="")
    sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: Não entendi  direito esse segundo bloco,  parece idêntico ao da pergunta. É isso mesmo?

Comment: Mas é o mesmo da pergunta, como ele já sabe que funciona e ele apenas estava com duvida do funcionamento, eu explique e então coloquei o código de novo para ele ler com as novas informações.

Comment: Eu entendi, @Bacco tranquilo.

Comment: @Cadu achei melhor perguntar. pois poderia ser intencional (conforme confirmado), um engano na hora de colar, ou mesmo eu não ter percebido a diferença. Como está esclarecido, jajá apago este comment aqui e os anteriores

Answer (score 3):

python tem o protocolo de iteração, onde toda a sequencia é um iterável, a prova disso é a implementação do método **iter** no objeto

```
dir('teste')#vc vai achar __iter__ no meio dos métodos
dir([1,2,3])#__iter__ também esta presente aqui
```